# send file with jquery and json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, mongodb

hi do not know how to send a structure containing a file right through ajax,
I need to send this structure as a json and contains an image I get an error in ajax,

```
    var professionalCardNumber = $("#professional_card_number_input").val();
    var professionalType = $("#professional_type_input").val();
    var isWorking = $("#is_working_input").val();
    var inputFileImage = document.getElementById("evidence_input");
    var evidence  = inputFileImage.files[0];

      e.preventDefault();
      var professionalInformation = {
        "professionalCard": {
          "number": professionalCardNumber
        },
        "professionalType": professionalType,
        "isWorking":isWorking,
        "evidence": evidence
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: requestType,
        url:"/api/v1/doctors/me/professional_information?errors=verbose",
        headers: {
          "accessToken": localStorage.accessToken
        },
        data:{
        professionalInformation:professionalInformation
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
```

Comment: What error? If it is relevant then where is your controller code? There are a quite a few tags on here where I only see Jquery code. So which part is your problem?

Comment: Sólo tengo que publicar la estructura que se encuentra en el código, ya que el servidor es bueno.
my problem is that I get to send an error structure for shipping ajax input file type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `JSON.stringify` on your data, along with the other relevant options:

```
$.ajax({ 
    "type": "POST", 
    "headers": { 
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "accessToken": localStorage.accessToken
    }, 
    "url": "/api/v1/doctors/me/professional_information?errors=verbose",
    "data": JSON.stringify(professionalInformation)
})
```

So you should have a `POST` or `PUT` verb here, but that is actually just whatever the endpoint should be expecting, (but those are best practice). The 'Content-type` header should also be there, but again you endpoint may just be presuming it is JSON.